# Как правильно вывести фигуру без деформации при разных разрешениях экрана?

Tags: графика, координаты

Допустим у нас экран квадратный и мы выводим в него круг (рисунок а), при этом он имеет правильную форму. Но на другом экране и другом разрешении он будет деформирован (рисунок b). Какой подход применяется при смене разрешения, что бы фигуры не деформировались?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня два варианта: либо масштабировать саму фигуру, либо менять координатную систему.

А что думаете или знаете вы по этому поводу? Ответ должен учитывать что графика бывает 2х и 3х мерной.

Comment: Как удобнее, так и делайте.

Comment: Обычно в UI меняют размеры фигур, а в копм. графике  - меняют систему координат

Comment: @PavelMayorov , а если пользоваться одним вариантом то какой приоритетней?

Comment: Который вам удобнее.

Comment: Чтобы вывести недеформированный круг, нужно просто рисовать круг, а не что-то другое. Значит, проблема не в круге, а в том, как определяется "фигура"